# Mot/expression polie permettant de décrire une personne d'âge mûr nouvellement employée par une entreprise

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je cherche un adjectif, ou plutôt un qualificatif qui permettrait de décrire en un mot ou deux la personne suivante:

Une personne nouvellement engagée dans une entreprise par un chasseur de tête (qui laisse donc penser qu'elle a une expérience de travail antérieure). Cette personne est d'âge 30-40-50 ans.

Je sais que le terme « nouvelle recrue » pourrait fonctionner, mais à mon sens il réfère plus à des nouveaux employés qui sont fraîchement diplômés, ou dans la vingtaine. De plus, je ne pourrais jamais dire à cette personne qui est plus âgée que moi « vous êtes une nouvelle recrue ». Je cherche un mot plus poli et parfaitement approprié.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vous êtes *récemment engagé* -- notez qu'ici, vous avez un adverbe "récemment" qui qualifie l'adjectif "engagé", au lieu d'un adjectif "nouvelle" qui qualifie un nom "recrue".

Answer (score 4):

La manière la plus courante de désigner un vieux dans le milieu professionnel est **un sénior**.

(Rappel et mise en garde pour prévenir d'éventuelles indignations : le terme *vieux* n'est pas une insulte. C'est un terme qui devrait même être honorifique pour toute personne n'ayant pas spécialement la haine de la vieillesse (de la sienne, de celle des autres). Inexplicablement, les mêmes personnes trouvent les termes *âgé* ou *sénior*, pour une raison qui m'échappe, moins offensants...)

Pour se référer à une personne présentant les deux caractéristiques (vieux *et* nouveau dans l'organisation), on composera une expression descriptive comme *un sénior récemment recruté*, ou autre. Il n'y a pas de terme spécifique existant qui résume les deux.

Comment: Mais à 30-40 ans on n'est pas encore un senior !

Comment: Mon avis est que comme l'âge peut être un motif de discrimination - au même titre que le sexe, la couleur etc - bien ce genre d'attribution participe du phénomène de [l'âgisme](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%82gisme) - et pourrait expliquer les indignations. Toujours à mon avis, c'est l'employé qui doit être décrit, et non la personne qui l'incarne. Un employé peut être expérimenté ou non indépendamment de l'âge. En plus, je crois que [senior](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/senior) rappelle l'anglais(_senior partner_ - associé principal/en chef etc.) où le sens est différent en contexte.

Comment: @Laure oui, je ne sais pas s'il y a une limite exacte, je l'imaginerais vers 40 ans probablement... je n'aime pas tellement ce terme, je voulais simplement rapporter qu'il est très employé (à tort ou à raison) dans le milieu professionnel.

Comment: @Laure En anglais on peut dire de quelqu'un que, par exemple, "he is **a 'senior'** software developer" lorsqu'il une dizaine d’années d’expérience (qui peut bien arriver dans ses trentaines).

Comment: @ChrisW You can't use *sénior*  that way in French. Low quality ads use it but it is bad translation from English. "A senior excutive" *cadre supérieur*, a "senior software developer" *un développeur logiciel de haut niveau*, etc.... *Sénior* is definitely linked to age in France. When job hunting  *sénior" usually means over 50. There's a national cross-industry agreement that fixes the seniority barrier at 45.

Comment: c'est senior pour 40-50, jeune senior, pour être "in" donc c'est déjà un style année 80. un element essentiel a l'entreprise. sur "pole emplois" , il y a exactement le jargon utile pour designer chacun des metiers de l'armée de terre puis les autres.

Comment: En athlétisme, on est senior de 23 à 39 ans puis vétéran au delà ...